# SQL SELECT statement containing AS

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I have the SQL query:

```
select title, scale / next_scale, c
from ( select title, scale, scale*D0 AS c, 
              lead(scale) over(partition by title order by scale asc) as next_scale,
              row_number() over(partition by title order by scale asc) as agg_row
       from signatures
     ) agg
where agg_row = 1;
```

and it works as expected. However, what I really want the sorting "scale" value to be an arithmetic operation between several columns, so I tried using an AS clause (shown above) and modify the query to:

```
select title, scale / next_scale, c
from ( select title, scale, scale*D0 AS c, 
              lead(scale) over(partition by title order by c asc) as next_scale,
              row_number() over(partition by title order by c asc) as agg_row
       from signatures
     ) agg
where agg_row = 1;
```

However, it fails at the `ORDER BY c`. Why is this? I can substitute `ORDER BY scale*D0` and it works just fine. However, I will eventually want to use a term like: `scale*D0*D1*D2*...*D100`; and I don't want to have to calculate that 3 different times - not to mention the physical length of the query. I am hoping to have `scale*D0*D1*D2*...*D100 AS c` and then `ORDER BY c`.

Is this possible?

I am using PostgreSQL.

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: I would try order by scale*D0

Comment: @Geoffrey: I would eventually like the terms to be scale*D0*D1*D2*...*D100, so I am trying to find a way to not repeat this 3 times. As of now though, I am leaning towards your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate `c` in a subquery:

```
select title, scale / next_scale, c
from ( select title, scale, c, 
              lead(scale) over(partition by title order by c asc) as next_scale,
              row_number() over(partition by title order by c asc) as agg_row
       from (select title, scale, scale * D0 AS c from signatures) signatures_calc
     ) agg
where agg_row = 1;
```

Comment: I should have just asked you in the first place ;-) Many many thanks, you have been such a big help with my last few queries. Works perfect! And simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can ORDER BY the ordinal number of the column:

```
select title, scale / next_scale, c
from ( select title, scale, scale*D0 AS c, 
          lead(scale) over(partition by title order by scale asc) as next_scale,
          row_number() over(partition by title order by scale asc) as agg_row
   from signatures
 ) agg
where agg_row = 1
order by 3;
```

Comment: thanks! I would like the "partition by title order by scale asc" to be something like "partition by title order by c asc" though, and that is what fails. Any thoughts?

Comment: I understand, and ordinal numbers will not help in the partition clause. It looks like you are stuck with the expression approach for partition by clause.

Answer (score 0):

When put the order by is the sub query, should fill the bill

```
select title, scale / next_scale, c
from ( select title, scale, scale*D0 AS c, 
          lead(scale) over(partition by title order by scale asc) as next_scale,
          row_number() over(partition by title order by scale asc) as agg_row
       from signatures
       order by 3
 ) agg
where agg_row = 1;
```